# Opaque WSDL schema error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, wsdl, visual-studio-2012, peoplesoft

Both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 give an opaque error when I try to import a PeopleSoft WSDL as a service reference.

I right-click on **Service References**, select **Add Service Reference**, paste the URL under **Address**, hit **Go**, then hit **OK**.

I get this opaque error:

[image: Opaque error message from Visual Studio]

http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas doesn't appear to resolve to anything, but I'm almost certain that doesn't matter.

I've also tested this in [soapUI](http://smartbear.com/products/open-source-tools/soapui) on the same PC as Visual Studio, and everything works correctly there. I can access the SOAP service and get expected responses.

The opaqueness of the error message is confusing, and this works in soapUI, so the WSDL is presumptively good? I've searched on this error and haven't found anything so far.

Here's the WSDL (sanitized to obscure URLs and service details):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE.1" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/schemas/A_PROGRAM_SERVICE.1" xmlns:A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" xmlns:A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/schemas/A_PROGRAM_SERVICE.1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy">
  <wsp:UsagePolicy wsdl:Required="true"/>
  <plnk:partnerLinkType name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_PartnerLinkType">
    <plnk:role name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_Provider">
      <plnk:portType name="tns:A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_PortType"/>
    </plnk:role>
  </plnk:partnerLinkType>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" schemaLocation="A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1.xsd"/>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" schemaLocation="A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1">
    <wsdl:documentation>A Data Repository</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:part element="A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1:InputParameters" name="parameter"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1">
    <wsdl:documentation>A Data Repository</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:part element="A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1:root" name="parameter"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="A_PROGRAM_OP">
      <wsdl:documentation>A Data Repository</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1" name="A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1" name="A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_Binding" type="tns:A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_PortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="A_PROGRAM_OP">
      <soap:operation soapAction="A_PROGRAM_OP.v1" style="document"/>
      <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameTokenSecurityPolicyPasswordOptional" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
          <wsp:All>
            <wsse:SecurityToken wsp:Usage="wsp:Required" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:TokenType>wsse:UserNameToken</wsse:TokenType>
              <Claims>
                <SubjectName MatchType="wsse:Exact"/>
                <UsePassword wsp:Usage="wsp:Optional"/>
              </Claims>
            </wsse:SecurityToken>
          </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
      </wsp:Policy>
      <wsdl:input name="A_PROGRAM_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1">
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="A_PROGRAM_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1">
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE">
    <wsdl:documentation>A Data Repository</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_Binding" name="A_PROGRAM_SERVICE_Port">
      <soap:address location="http://some_url_here/PSIGW/PeopleSoftServiceListeningConnector/SYSTEMNAME"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you post the URL for this WSDL? The only thing odd I see is that the same namespace is used for two imports.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks! Unfortunately, the URL is not accessible outside of my institutional network.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Sorry, pressed enter too quickly. Is it wrong to use the same namespace twice? But maybe that explains the error. I'll see what happens if I change the namespace for the 2nd instance.

Comment: I'm not sure about same namespace twice, but I'm not sure about the same namespace being imported into from two separate schema files.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer below. One of the XSDs has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With deeper analysis, I figured it out. One of the imported XSDs has `maxOccurs="unbounded"`  in the root element. This makes no sense because the root element can only appear once in an XML document.

Visual Studio sure could use a more clear error message!

Thanks to @JohnSaunders for helping me think about checking the imports.

Comment: I've confirmed that this was it. The service owner removed the `maxOccurs` attribute from the XSD, and it works fine now. Microsoft needs to do a better job with its error messages!